Can I pass a child component as a prop from the parent. And then have it pass onto futher set children?
I might be doing this completely wrong, but here goes.
I'm using the Tabs from Chakra as part of the navigation on my webapp.
I'm currently manually writing the names on each Tab, and then calling the component. Each return in the individual components is wrapped in a TabPanel.
function TabNav(){
    return(<Tabs variant='soft-rounded' colorScheme='green'>
    <TabList>
      <Tab>Report</Tab>
      <Tab>FoodItems</Tab>
      <Tab>Incident</Tab>
      <Tab>FormSubmit</Tab>
  
    </TabList>
  
    <TabPanels>
      
        <Report/>
        <FoodItems/>
        <Incident/>
        <TabPanel>
        <SubmitReport/>
        </TabPanel>

  </TabPanels>

</Tabs>

This works, but it doesn't neither scalable, modular and it will be hopeless to keep track off.
Is there a way where I can pass the components as props to the , or is there a different way to go about it? I wanted it to be called once, then rendered both in the Tab and TabPanel With pseudo code something like this

import { foodItems, Report, Incident, SubmitReport } "from file"

<Tabs variant='soft-rounded' colorScheme='green'>
    <TabList>
      <Tab "<Report/>">Report.title</Tab>
      <Tab "<FoodItems/>">FoodItems.title/></Tab>
      <Tab "<Incident/>">Incident.title</Tab>
      <Tab "<SubmitReport/>">SubmitReport.title</Tab>
  
    </TabList>
         
    <TabPanels>
    
        <TabPanel>
            Report.render
        </TabPanel>

        <TabPanel>
            FoodItems.render
        </TabPanel>
            Incident.render        
         <TabPanel>
            SubmitReport.render        
        </TabPanel>

<TabPanel>
        
        </TabPanel>
  </TabPanels>

</Tabs>

Sorry for the lack of formal structure. But I can't really describe it any better
I really don't know what to google or try for this one

Not entirely sure what you need but I would be careful of overengineering here. You don't want to get into a situation where you are dynamically rendering static tabs. You won't actually gain a great benefit by tying the tab names to their components in a single object. Follow the way Chakra suggests since you are using that package.

The idea behind React is that you really, really don't. You make sure you underlying data has the correct values, and then your components build the corresponding UI with that. So you don't move "children", you simply updated one list to have one object fewer, and some other child component's props to have one object more, so that React can turn that into the corresponding UI. When you're trying to move DOM nodes around, that's pretty much the biggest sign that you're still thinking in terms of "how you'd do it in plain JS" instead of writing code the React way.

I was considering this to be a part of my problem to the aproach. As I feel someoen confident writing plain JS, but very much unfamiliar with react.
The curiousity stems from thinking the "add to list here", then add components there, wold be hard to keep track of. For me by myself, its not a problem, but for example where someone else were to use the code?

If I understood correctly, you're trying to find a way to make adding/removing items from your Tabs component in a better way, right?
One thing you could do is, pass an array of objects with a title and component props that could be used to render the children of TabList and TabPanels dynamically.
Something like this?

Define an options array somewhere in the parent of TabNav:

const options = [
  { id: 'report', title: 'Report', component: <Report /> },
  { id: 'food_items', title: 'Food Items', component: <FoodItems /> },
  { id: 'incident', title: 'Incident', component: <Incident /> },
  { id: 'submit_report', title: 'Submit Report', component: <SubmitReport /> },
] // pass this to TabNav as props from the parent.


Refactor your TabNav component to use this options array to render your components.

function TabNav({ options }) {
  return(
    <Tabs variant='soft-rounded' colorScheme='green'>
      <TabList>
        {
          options.map((item) => (
            <Tab key={item.id}>{item.title}</Tab>
          )
        }
      </TabList>
  
      <TabPanels>
        {
          options.map((item) => (
            <TabPanel key={item.id}>{item.component}</TabPanel>
          )
        }
      </TabPanels>
    </Tabs>
  );
}

The benefit of doing this is that you're delegating the logic of how to render your tabs to TabNav while keeping the content itself to be decided by whoever uses TabNav.
